# Vertical Center Content jQuery and FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I have a jQuery script that centers a div vertically. It appears that it is doing is job in all browsers but in FireFox.  When I refresh the screen, the div centers as intended.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    centerContent();
});


$(window).load(function()
{
    centerContent();
});

$(window).resize(function()
{
    centerContent();
});

function centerContent()
{
    var height = $(document).height();
    var divHeight = $('#wrapper').height();
    var lNavHeight = $('#lNav').height();
    var diff = height/2 - divHeight/2;
    $('#wrapper').css({"position": "relative", "top": diff});
    $('#lNav').css({"position": "absolute", "bottom": 45});
    $('#rNav').css({"position": "absolute", "bottom": 45, "right": 5});
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside if you are calling centerContent on different events you can bind them in one go in jquery. $(window).on("load resize", function(){
centerContent(); 
});

Comment: And you should be able to align something centrally and vertically in pretty much all browsers only using css.

Comment: Maybe if you put your code in a jsfiddle, the community could help (myself included). http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: lharby is right, when i need to do that I basically set the container to `display:table-cell` and had a `vertical-align:middle;` so the child block just need `margin:auto;`for horizontal alignement.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I was able to achieve what I was looking for by changing `code` var height = $(document).height(); `code`to var height = $(window).height(). This is what I want to achieve ultimately, but it is getting it done by brute force.http://jsfiddle.net/gz9m771p/3/

Answer (score 1):

Better use a pure CSS solution like this (make sure to add vendor prefixes):

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
#content {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">CENTERED CONTENT</div>
</div>
```